# Adapting existing Web page

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

How to adapt existing web page for iphone and androids?
I already tried using CSS and set my page on percentages.

Is there any way except completely rebuilding a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Media Queries or User Agents to detect the type of device and then you can load in extra style-sheets or javascript files to account for the environment change.
Could you try using viewport tags?

For example:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Look those tags up to confirm.  I just typed the one above from memory.

Comment: Please don't sign posts. Your user card at the bottom right of the answer is enough.

Comment: My task this is to create a website in HTML5. Page must fit a screen size of mobile (iPhone, Android) and a normal computer.

Comment: Oh, I did not even realize I did that until you pointed it out.  I guess it is just habit.  Thanks

Comment: Building layouts for mobile and desktop environments combined can be tricky, but is for the most part, pure CSS driven.  Chances are you might just have to reformat your layout to account for both environments.